# error trying to connect to mysql server using command line on windows machine

Tags: mysql

can anyone point out where is the mistake in the command.

```
mysql-> connect -h 192.168.1.4 -u  xxxxx-p error:ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'fis-lap-106.fs.local' (using
    password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you intended to use a password, but you didn't put a space before the `-p`

Answer (score 0):

The error is defined [here](http://webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html).

> User is not allowed to connect from the actual host. Note that MySQL by default only allows connection from 'localhost'. To specify from where a user may connect SQL wildcards (% and _) can be used. Simply 'someuser@%' means that user 'someuser' may connect from everywhere.

Comment: but am not still able to connect using cosole ..but the same i can connect using php.